# Android Call a method from adapter

Tags: java, android, fragment, adapter

I have a method in a fragment that I want to call when user clicks a recyclerview item. For example

```java
holder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call the method in fragment
                //e.g.  activity instance context dot(.) method name
                mainActivity.refreshData();
            }
   }
```

In main activity it will be simple as

```
public void refreshData(){
     // refresh
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface of a click listener:

```
interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick();
}
```

Add this listener to your `RecyclerView` adapter's constructor:

```
private final ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public MyAdapter(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}
```

And add there the click listener for your `addButton`:

```
holder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onItemClick();
    }
}
```

Pass the implementation of `ItemClickListener` interface to your adapter in your activity class, for example like this:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(() -> refreshData());
```

Answer (score 1):

This **function** is in your `main-class`:

```
    public void refreshData(){
     // refresh
}
```

Now can Call that **function** in your adapter by this.

```
holder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call the method in fragment
                //e.g.  activity instance context dot(.) method name
             ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(context)).refreshData();
            }
   }
```

**Note**: you need to pass the fragment `context` to your adapter.
Here is the exmaple code how I passed the context from `main-class` to **fragment** then **fragment** to the `adapter`.

```
Context context;
   public ProfileFragment(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
  adapter = new ProfileTimelineAdapter(context, modelFeedArrayList);
```